# how to convert text to image in kinetic js version 5.1.0

Tags: angularjs, html, kineticjs

My following code work fine with kineticjs version 4.4.3 but give error with kineticjs version 5.1.0 (as shown in screen shot)
[image]
Code is:

var simpleText = new Kinetic.Text({
      x: 50,
      y: 50,
      text: 'TESTING',
      fontSize: 16,
      fill: "white"
    });
    simpleText.toImage({
        width:50,
        height:50,
        x : 50,
        y : 50,
        callback: function(img){
          var yodaImg = new Kinetic.Image({
              image: img,
              x: 0,
              y: 0,
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              name: 'image'
          });
          console.log(yodaImg.src);
        }
    });

For some reasons I have to use this latest version.
Any solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var textOnCanvas = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    text: fullText,
    fontFamily: "Arial",
    fontSize: 22,
    fill: '#000000',
    align: 'left',
    padding: 5,
    width: 1024
 });
layer.add(textOnCanvas);
layer.draw();

var textImgSrc = textOnCanvas.toDataURL(); // base64 image of text

var textImgObj = new Image();
textImgObj.src = textImgSrc;
var kineticIMG = new Kinetic.Image({
    image: textImgObj,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
});
```

src will be in base64 string. Then you can apply this image to the Kinetic.Image() object.

Comment: Giving error 'cannot read property _applyTransform of null' on this line         var imgFromTextSrc = simpleText.toDataURL();    while simpleText is still the same

Comment: make this:
layer.add(simpleText);
layer.draw();
and then: var imgFromTextSrc = simpleText.toDataURL();
after that make layer.removeChildren(); and work with your new image

Comment: this process do remove the error but generate empty image

Comment: may be we just have to set x and y in .toDataUrl(); ?? is there any way?

Comment: I updated answer and put full version from my project. It's 100% working.
Maybe you are using old version of KineticJS.
And, for your information - new framework - KonvaJS is a fork of KineticJS and realized more new things with all old stuff from KineticJS